# Protecting methods using Laravel 5 Auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a bunch of controllers. One of them is `ArticleController`. I want the method `postCreateArticle()` method to require the user to be authenticated.

In the documentation, I figured you can use the `auth` middleware, like so:

```
Route::get('profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', function()
{
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
}]);
```

However, I am registering my controllers in the `routes`:

```
Route::controller('articles', 'ArticleController');
```

How do I protect the `postCreateArticle()` method, without doing it inside the method?

Comment: I programmed a permission/role module for Laravel which allows you to protect methods or complete controllers: https://github.com/cgrossde/Laraguard

Comment: The doc provide a sample of specifying a *middleware* to *controller route* here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#controller-middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor you should be able to:

```
$this->middleware('auth', ['only' => 'postCreateArticle'])
```